# Pymongo returns subdocs as dicts instead of SONs?

Tags: encoding, pymongo

Is there a way to have pymongo return subdocs as SONs so they can be successfully passed back in for find queries? GridFS is returning the `file._id` as a dict instead of a SON; so, the subsequent call to `grid_file.GridOut.read` is failing to find the grid file. (I know, using dicts as _id is asking for trouble, but I'm dealing w/ an existing db/system.)

I don't see how I can intervene to coerce the `file._id` into the correctly ordered SON.

Comment: please include a short snippet demonstrating the problem

Answer (score 0):

The `MongoClient.document_class` field controls this! Just add `document_class=bson.son.SON,` to the constructor